# How to differentiate between who sent the messages in the photon chat other than usernames?

Tags: unity-game-engine, chat, multiplayer, photon

So I have created a chat system for Multiplayer and it is working fine but I want a change in my UI so that player recognizes that messages were sent by other user or not. I have attached a picture for ref.
White background should be personal user while brown be other clients.

[My Chat UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQFId.png)

But I am not getting how to do that , any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you sent the message by using `photonView.isMine();` with that you can change whatever you want based on is the message yours or another users